# is it possible to apply two tax rates on single product in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database

I have created two tax rates in magento 1.9.2.
[image]
[image]

applied both in single rule.
[image]

only one tax rate showing in cart and checkout page.
[image]

is it possible to apply two tax rates on single product in magento 1.9.2?

Comment: Shall i know what the scenario you need. 
can you explain in brief

Comment: so you needed 18% of Tax am i correct?

Comment: yes, I need to add two tax 9% + 9%